# Node - ENONET when connecting to a socket

Tags: node.js, sockets

Executing this code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Socket = require('net').Socket;

var socket = new Socket();

console.log('connecting to: ' + server.host + ':' + server.port );

socket.connect( server.host, server.port );

socket.on('error', function(err) {

    console.log(arguments);
});

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');
});

socket.on('end', function() {
    console.log('socket ended');
});
```

Always throws this error:

```
{ '0': { [Error: connect ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'connect' } }
```

I'm on CloudLinux(x64) based shared hosting with SSH access.

Comment: What do `server.host` and `server.port` resolve to? i.e. are they sane?

Comment: **irc.twitch.tv:6667**, I can connect to the same IP:Port with PHP fsockopen

Comment: It's likely to be backwards arguments to `socket.connect`. See my answer below.

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes it is, 6667 port was just blocked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have your host and port backwards. According to [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_port_host_connectlistener), you should be doing:

```
socket.connect(server.port, server.host);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Server Side:-**

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(functi`on (socket){
  socket.write("hi\n");
  socket.write("you there\n");
  socket.on("data", function(dd) {
    console.log(data);
    });
  });


server.listen(8001);
```

**Client side:-**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Sock = require('net');

var socket = Sock.Socket();

socket.connect(8001,"127.0.0.1", function() {

    console.log('connecting to: ' + server.host + ':' + server.port );
});

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');
});

socket.on('error', function(err) {

    console.log(arguments);
});

socket.on('end', function() {
    console.log('socket ended');
});
```

Comment: You're using the connect callback and event. Why not just use one of them?

Comment: you can do it with any way you like but use events inside the callback is good approach